# Property 'ObjectID' does not exist on type 'CollectionStatic'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript

I am getting this error while using MongoDB npm module

```
mongoId = new Mongo.Collection.ObjectID()._str;
```

Please see the attached pic also.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: this is `new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID()` meteor function i guess not a  mongodb function

Comment: I am using Mongo Id in my app.

Comment: are you using mongoose ?

Comment: No, Just Mongo Object Id.

Answer (score 0):

> Require mongodb npm module and then get id like this

```
    ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID
    // Create a new ObjectID
    var objectId = new ObjectID();
```